# Simplifying terms by substitution and/or elimination

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I would like to simplify the output of a calculation.

For example, in the output image below, `y^3` and `y^(5/2)` can be simplified to be `y`, and the result of the integral would be simply `(3/2)*y`. How can I make Mathematica simplify as such?

Is the output in this format because of the condition `y>0`, and a simplification would omit this condition?

[image: enter code here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you can justify that y>0

```
Simplify[ConditionalExpression[3/2 Sqrt[1/y^3]y^(5/2),Re[y]>0],y>0]
```

which instantly returns

```
(3*y)/2
```

I assume you have previously assigned a value to k which isn't shown. You could wrap the

```
Simplify[...,y>0]
```

around your Integrate and do all this simplification in one step if you have done that assignment to k.

Or you can look at the documentation for Integrate and click on the orange Details and Options and look at the option of giving Assumptions directly to Integrate and it might make use of those to produce a simpler result directly.

Comment: Thank you, this resolves my issue!